# problem with image display in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have got a strange problem. Can somebody look into it please.
I have a folder called "img" in my website. I added a new image to it.
Now the strange problem is that when I give img/imagename.extension it doesn't display in the browser.

I have tried even ~/img. But ended nothing. Actually I am using the image in the spark template. I have taken an existing image and tried, it displays the existing image but not the one I have added. I was expecting may be I need to check in the newly added image but even doing that didn't end up the result.

Any ideas????

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you using Razor use @Url.Content("~/img/yourimage.ext")

Comment: I am not using razor but your answer helped me in another scenario. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if authorisation rules of the folder img prevent the images from being shown e.g. to not authorised users.
2. Check if the image file was properly added to the solution in the VS.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I tried to set the authorization rules of the folder to get full control but still I face the same problem

Comment: I's hard to say more from your somehow too general description. Please update your question with more relevant information, e.g. declarative code or code behind where you address your image. Before you do that just one more idea: Have you tried to rename your image with the name of the existing one? The reason may be that sometimes templates are being animated with JavaScript and it can influence your representation if you do not take it into account while adding another image.